# Image Resizer not resizing locally

Tags: azure, imageresizer

I am using ImageResizer with the AzureReader2 plugin on an ASP.NET MVC application.

When I type `http://localhost:[port]/[prefix]/[blobname]` on the address bar I get redirected to `[endpoint]/[blobname]`, and I am able to see my image.

But I can't use any query string, for example typing `http://localhost:[port]/[prefix]/[blobname]?width=200` gives me the IIS HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found page. I've tried setting `redirectToBlobIfUnmodified` to both true and false, but I get the same result.

When I host the image locally, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by including the container name in the url:

`http://localhost:[port]/[prefix]/[containername]/[blobname]?width=200`

Using this method, it's the original image that gets broken. In those cases, I would just have to use the raw blob storage url.